graphs which have polynomial bounded number of cycles
How does the graph class defined as those graphs which have polynomial (or quasi polynomial) bounded number of cycles look? (in number of vertices)
I suspect it will rather non-interesting as something very close to a tree (maybe bounded treewidth) but a reference would be nice.

What does it mean for a graph to "have polynomial bounded number of cycles"? For any given graph the number of cycles is a constant. It makes sense (although in general probably isn't interesting) to pick a specific polynomial $P$ and ask about the class of graphs $(V, E)$ for which the number of cycles is bounded by $P(|V|)$; and it potentially makes sense to ask for which graph classes we can define a polynomial $Q$ such that all graphs $(V, E)$ in that class have number of cycles bounded by $Q(|V|)$, but neither of those appear to be what you're asking about.

@PeterTaylor The second interpretation. I mean it in the sense that for a graph family where there is a graph $G_n$ on $n$ vertices for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there is a polynomially $f(n)$ such that the number of cycles in $G_n$ is bounded by $f(n)$. This is true for trees for instance, but false for planar graphs.
